# Google Sheets: convert currency to USD based on currency shown in cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I use a Google Sheet to track ebook sales, some of which are international. Column `H` below has the royalty amount that was paid out for the sale, but that amount is still shown in the sale currency, as seen in Column `F`. I'd like to be able to convert the royalty amount to USD using a formula. I found one formula that comes close to what I want...it takes the money amount shown in a cell (e.g. `A2`) and converts it from one currency to another (GBP to USD in this case).

`=A2*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPUSD")`

However, this formula obviously requires you to enter both the base currency and the conversion currency, and I'd have to change it every time I needed to convert something besides GBP. Since I'll always be converting the sale currency to USD, is there a way to write a similar formula that takes the amount from Column `H`, looks at the currency listed in Column `F`, and converts that to USD?

[image]

Comment: Finally. Good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following.

```
=IF(LEN(A2),IFERROR(D2*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&B2&"USD"&""),D2),)
```

Copy down till it meets your needs.

[image]

Functions used:

- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`GOOGLEFINANCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281)

Comment: Must be the fastest answer in webapps. LOL

Comment: Haha! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Will do. Just waiting for the 5 minutes to be up so it actually lets me accept an answer :)

Comment: Thanx. This was fun. Stay safe. Happy seasons.